# JSON templating in JAVA

Tags: java, json, parsing, templates, jackson

I have two JSON files.

first.json

```
{ 
    "sentence" : "{{place_name}} is {{adj}} place"
}
```

second.json

```
{
    "place_name" : "New York",
    "adj" : "a nice"
}
```

I am using [Jackson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson) to parse JSON in JAVA. How can I use second file's object/parameters in the first one?

An obvious solution would be string parsing. Identify what are the placeholders in the first one which needs replacement. If they are available in second's object replace it with the corresponding value.

Is there any JSON templating library available which facilitates this directly without going through the pain of manual parsing?

Though JSON content is not for dynamic modifications, is there any way values in JSON can be dynamic?  If yes, a nice parsing solution in Java would be?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in three steps. Parse second.json with Jackson. For each of the dicts you get, use something like Freemarker to do the string templating for the sentence, then use Jackson for the JSON generation with the strings your templating engine generated.

Basically, use the right tool for the job, then chain the results together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template framework like freemarker. 
And convert json data to Map/List form using [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) library so it can be used by template framework.